# Running vector autoregressions with non-stationary data

Tags: econometrics, time-series, oil, stationary

I am reading Diego Kaenzig ["The Macroeconomic Effects of Oil Supply News: Evidence from OPEC Announcements"](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3185839). I have a question about the baseline specification and in particular the treatment of non-stationary variables.

I understand that all variables must be stationarized prior to conducting VAR analysis. However, that isn't what he seems to do. Instead, he takes the logs and continues. The variables I am confused about are US Industrial Production and World Industrial Production, which certainly contain an upward trend and are not stationary. Even when taking the logs of these variables, they are still growing.

Could someone please explain why this is not an issue in this paper? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @SandPadres. In the notes of page 3, the author makes reference to the variables which have been first-differenced/stationarised. Hope this helps. I've also read papers in the past where this is discreet.